# UITableView in a normal View Controller is not updating with my custom cells

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a TableView placed within a normal View Controller that displays some simple data I have pulled from a JSON. The cell has only labels. In my ViewController Class, I have the following code, but my table view is not displaying the data still:

```
import UIKit

class EmployeePortal: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!

    var appData:Array<Dictionary<String,String>>? = nil
    var numberOfApps:Int = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self

        let currentDate = Date()
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .full
        let date = dateFormatter.string(from: currentDate)
        dateLabel.text = date

         /////Methods to get data....////

            do{
                let JSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! Array<Dictionary<String,String>>
                self.appData = JSON
                print(self.appData)  ///test just to make sure data is coming in
                self.numberOfApps = JSON.count

            //JSON file contains everything needed to make appointments
            }catch{
                print("ERROR DOWNLOADING JSON")
            }
        }
        task.resume()
      ///I think my problem might be here, not sure how to make the table 
     //actually load the data
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // There is only one section 
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //The number of rows is equal to the amount of appointments the data returned:
        return self.numberOfApps
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "appCell", for: indexPath) as! appCell  //made sure to use my custom cell
        let row = indexPath.row
        cell.patientName.text = self.appData?[row]["pName"]
        cell.reasonLabel.text = self.appData?[row]["reason"]
        cell.dateLabel.text = self.appData?[row]["date"]
        return cell //do all the stuff to update the labels and return it
    }


}
```

Not sure what else I am missing. I have the table view's delegates and data sources set up appropriately. I guess its something small I am missing but I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Try setting the the method to get the data in `viewWillAppear`. Assuming you're using storyboard did you connect the outlets of the tableview to the controller?

Comment: The outlets of tableview are both connected to the controller as well as delegate/data source. I did put my data loading functions into my viewWillAppear class instead but the tableView still does not load the cells data

Comment: @AndrasPalfi i am wonder i did not find  any response from for this problem  . did solved your problem if so  please share answer . for future reader

Comment: @NazmulHasan I ended up explicitly specifying my appData as an empty Array of Dictionaries and i was ok!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DispatchQueue.main.async` - for update  the UI why because  network call is  background queue .

try this way

```
 do{
        let JSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! Array<Dictionary<String,String>>
           self.appData = JSON
           print(self.appData)  ///test just to make sure data is coming in
           self.numberOfApps = JSON.count
           DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                 self.tableView.reloadData()  
           })
            //JSON file contains everything needed to make appointments
  }
  catch{
      print("ERROR DOWNLOADING JSON")
  }
```

Update : -

```
if let pName =  (self.appData[row]["pName"]) as? String {
   cell.patientName.text = pName
}
```

Comment: So this worked, but I ran into a new error. Now, in my `cellForRowAt` method it will not let me update the text of the labels in the cells with my data, it is saying it unexpectedly found a nil value while unwrapping an optional, even though I checked to make sure it is not null and also I forced it to be not optional: `cell.patientName.text = (self.appData[row]["pName"])!` is where the error is thrown. I printed the type of (self.appData[row]["pName}]) and it is in fact String, not Optional(String)

Comment: try with option binding `if let ` and check my update section and let me know